# Limited user's token scope on user password grant flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, passwords, keycloak

I have a Keycloak instance with :

- `user1` / `password1`
- `user2` / `password2`
- `client` / `secret` with Direct Access Grants Enable and scopes : `resourceA`, `resourceB`

When I do a password grant flow like :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://keycloak.instance/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user1' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password1'
```

I want to retrieve a token with the scope : `resourceA` and NOT `resourceB`.
And when the same call is made using `user2`, I want ONLY `resourceB` scope.

Is there a way to configure this rule in Keycloak to only have a token with an intersection of `scope/role` of the client and the grant user ?

Comment: User doesn't have relation to scope. It has only relations to roles/groups, so I would say you can't this `scope` magic without hacking. Why you don't use user roles/groups (role/group mapper)?

Comment: We migrate the security layer from basic auth to oauth2 client credentials in our micro services fleet. To consume our open API, external clients will have to migrate too. During this transition period, we added a new component to convert the basic user/password authorization header to an bearer access token header using a password grant flow. Is there a way to map user role and client scope ?